# sharepoint 2013 Literal content (' ') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelTriggerCollection'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My SharePoint application gives this error
after I put the Fontawesome link [Fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) online link in my master page:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It gives error as below:

> Literal content (' ') is not allowed within a System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelTriggerCollection'

I removed the font link but still the error exist.
I don't know what is the cause of this error and how to solve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Literal content (' ') is actually an html non-breaking space that gets added when editing the page in SharePoint Designer for the first time. It appears around line 354 of the default seattle.master page [I haven't tried with the other default master pages].

```
      <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="WebPartAdder" />
    &nbsp; </Triggers>
```

Remove the `$nbsp;` and save the page again to clear the error. I found that after it is removed the first time its won't re-appear in future edits.

Comment: Great.It worked!!. it saved lots of my time. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The same issue was happened with me once, but I searched this for and found that my **Content Placeholders** were in small letter. After I changed them to capitalized form the issue was resolved for me.

In case if you are using page layout with this, verify the same for **Content** in page layout also.

If you find this as right solution, mark this as answer. So others can get their solutions too. :)